# Stream reading a file in php

Tags: php, memory

I have a big csv file ( about 30M ), that I want to read using my php program and convert it to another format and save it as different small files . When I am using the traditional fopen , fwrite methods I am getting an error that says `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted` . I am aware that I can set the memory limit in php.ini but is there any way that I can read the file as stream so that it wont create much memory overhead ? May be something like `StreamReader` classes in java ?

Comment: Can you post the code? I think you are reading all of the source file at once or maybe allocate memory for each small file, which isn't freed inbetween.

Comment: @GolezTrol yes that was right . Wiseguy 's answer fixed the issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just read the file one line at a time with [`fgets()`](http://php.net/fgets), provided you are reassigning your variable each time through (and not storing the lines in an array or something, where they would remain in memory).

One way, with a ~65 MB file:

```
// load the whole thing
$file = file_get_contents('hugefile.txt');
echo memory_get_peak_usage() / 1024 / 1024, ' MB';
// prints '66.153938293457 MB'
```

Second way:

```
// load only one line at a time
$fh = fopen('hugefile.txt', 'r');
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {}
echo memory_get_peak_usage() / 1024 / 1024, ' MB';
// prints '0.62477111816406 MB'
```

Also, if you want to rearrange the data in a different format, you could parse each line as CSV as you go using [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) instead.